# How I create a query which return who is the driver between 2 dates?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have 2 tables:

```
log: LogId, UnitId, LogTime etc...

driver_log: DriverLogId, UnitId, DriverId, StartTime, StopTime
```

The log table's have 400+ million rows. For example I need all record today from log (its ~300-350 rows) and I need who drive the Unit row by row.

Please help me, i don't have any idea.

Comment: So, you have 3000 years worth of data?

Comment: nope, just 7.5 :)

Comment: Have you tried any query? If not please do, if yes provide the query you tried.

Comment: So today is a quiet day? Normally, you'd expect to have 14 - 15 thousand rows in a day? Or maybe, you actually have more like 400+ *thousand* rows!

Comment: 1 unit create ~600-800 rows/day, we have 300+ units

Answer (score 0):

> i don't have any idea

Well we also don't have a good idea what you want, but the query below joins together your two tables and returns only logs which are from today.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM log t1
INNER JOIN driver_log t2
    ON t1.UnitId = t2.UnitId
WHERE DATE(t1.LogTime) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second date is before your first date (ie. you are querying between September 29 2010 and January 30 2010). Try reversing the order of the dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Comment: without join how to fetch data from two tables?

Comment: @KarthiVenture You can use shoulder if loin is unavailable.

Comment: can you please explain little bit more? @Strawberry